# Aggregate Function with Partition By

Tags: sql-server-2008

I need to add an additional column which will get the total sales %. I've attempted to do so by adding:

```
Book_sales / SUM(Book_sales ) As 'Total_Sales%'
```

However, this will not work. Because this is an aggregate function, SQL requires that I would group publ_id which I do not want to do[image]

Comment: What is wrong with the query in your screenshot? From where I'm sitting, it looks like it works and it seems the way to do the job too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should join your query with grouping query with totals:

```
SELECT 
    ....
    OD.Quantity*OD.Order_price / SUM_OD.Book_Total As 'Total_Sales%'      
    ....

FROM Books AS BKS
INNER JOIN order_details AS OD ON BKS.book_id=OD.book_id
INNER JOIN 
  ( SELECT book_id,
           SUM(Quantity*Order_price) as Book_Total
     FROM order_details 
     GROUP BY book_id
  ) AS SUM_OD ON BKS.book_id=SUM_OD.book_id
```